# Creating two application interface framework on recieving one idoc

Tags: interface, abap, idoc

I want to create multiple AIF on a single recieving IDOC based on basic type or message type or variant or any other criteria.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if an IDoc can trigger 2 AIF interfaces simultaneously, the answer is no.

What you can do is to assign an IDoc to multiple AIF interfaces, and then choose which one to be executed based on the IDoc content.

In `/AIF/CUST` transaction choose

> SAP Application Interface Framework -> Interface Development ->
>   Additional Interface Properties -> Assign IDoc Types

here you can assign 2 or more interface to a message/idoc type

[image: Assign Idoc Types]

Then choose

> SAP Application Interface Framework -> System Configuration ->
>   Interface Determination -> Define Interface Determination for IDoc
>   Interfaces

here you can determine which interface to execute when an IDoc is received based on few fields (in this example I'm using Sender partner from control record)

choose the IDoc field used as a condition
[image: Filter fields]

choose which value of the field trigger each interface

[image: Values]